# Silverlight - Read version of another assembly in local directory

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, .net-assembly

All,

I need to read version number of an assembly in local directory (My document directory to be exact) in my out-of-browser app w/ elevated trust. I cannot use the Assembly.Load, Assembly.LoadFrom methods because these cannot be used in Silverlight (marked w/ security exception attribute).

I know how to load it File.ReadAllBytes(), but then I need the steps to get my hands on the manifest and get the version number.

lk

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with .NET, but not (directly) with Silverlight.

That's because there is no .NET library (as far as I know) that reads assemblies.

With .NET, you can load the assembly in a separate app domain and get the version there.

If you are really desperate, you can embed a .NET application (an .exe file) in your Silverlight application that gets written out and executed from Silverlight.

I've done that before for a different problem.

Feel free to ask me for some code for either of those issues if you really want to pursue this path.